# Sprite Collisions, Invisible Rectangles

Tags: java, sprite

As a programmer my only interest is in making games, and for that sprite collisions are absolutely necessary I already know that a rectangle will be needed around my sprite, but how do I go about not making the user see it?I was thinking about drawing it before the background but are there any other ways that you guys know about?

Comment: Just want to hear your diverse solutions

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer for your current question?

Comment: No, I have made my own method of sprite collision checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collision boxes are not physical rectangles drawn to the screen. They are constructed through a series of conditional statements that check bounds of a sprite. It's hard to give an example without code, but you can find examples of this process in many tutorials found on YouTube.

For Example, take this piece of code from [DesignsByZepher's Tutorials](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8CAB66181A502179):

```
public boolean hasCollided(int xa,int ya) {
        int xMin = 0;
        int xMax = 7;
        int yMin = 3;
        int yMax = 7;

        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++)   {
            if (isSolidTile(xa,ya,x,yMin))  {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++)   {
            if (isSolidTile(xa,ya,x,yMax))  {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int y = yMin; y < xMax; y++)   {
            if (isSolidTile(xa,ya,xMin,y))  {
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int y = yMin; y < xMax; y++)   {
            if (isSolidTile(xa,ya,xMax,y))  {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying(checking the xoordinates of another sprite regarding to the coordinates, width and height of another sprite), thanks for your answer.